# Same content of divs only via HTML+CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to apply the same **content** to two (or more) divs using just HTML + CSS?

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="same"></div>
    abc
    <div class="same"></div>
    def
    <div class="same"></div>
<body>
```

**CSS**

```
.same
{
     //styling code
}
```

Is it possible for those three divs to have the same content like {content} without using any JavaScript?

**NOTE**
I need it for a presentation purposes in case if in a user browser JS is switched off

Comment: What's your use-case? Are those elements presentational, or should they be actual content with which users can interact?

Comment: presentation of course. My example might suggest that otherwise, sorry for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fv9wx/2/) - CSS

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fv9wx/1/) - JS

In a way, yes. However should it be used like this? No.

CSS doesn't *immediately* control content and should only be used for styling. You can use `::after` and `::before`, but they shouldn't be used for content. However, it's your code so you can do what you like.

HTML:

```
<div class="same"></div>

<div class="same"></div>

<div class="same"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.same:after{
    content:"Using content, yes!";
}
```

If you want to use javascript, you could do this:

```
var same = document.getElementsByClassName('same'), //'same' variable gets all 'same' class
i = same.length; //gets amount of elements with class of 'same'

while(i--) { //while 'i' is a number above 0 (but taking 1 away each time)
  same[i].innerHTML = "Same Text!"; //Set each element's text with class of 'same' to 'Same Text!'
}
```

This method won't require any jQuery so will still work without having to add any external files.

Comment: This is what i was looking for. im trying to create a simply div that wil align itself to ther right and point to user, that this menu item has submenu. sort of icon from jQuery UI. 
having it done this way changing char > for --> if needed will be done in one pleace.
But this is not working under IE right? i guess i'll have to do it via javascript :(

Comment: @T.G JavaScript is your best bet. CSS reacts different in different browsers and on some older browsers, some CSS styles don't work at all. With javascript, you'll at least get the same result throughout every browser.

Comment: I know what you mean, im just trying to do stuff other way.
At this moment, im editing a given html file, and i'm trying to avid putting JS code in it. Jut changing components with i suppose to change and my own css code putting to separate file

Answer (score 2):

No. CSS does not control content.

Well, mostly. You can use the :before and :after pseudo-class content, but that should really be reserved for UI elements, not actual content,

Comment: There is no `:after` pseudoclass, there is `::after` pseudoclass and 2  `:` are not without reason. `::after` will show when you will set, yeah, **content**. Dont tell **content** isnt content. btw. Yes, CSS controls content too, you can even overwrite existing content in working CSS4. Answers like this makes me sick.

Comment: @Benio...In fact you are both wrong. `:after` and :`before` are pseudo-elements not pseudo-classes. Since CSS4 is not yet implemented there is zero point in mentioning it and **still** the `content' property should not be used for **actual** content. That's what HTML is for. CSS is for **styling**.

Comment: Yes, they are pseudo–elements, my fault, sorry.

Comment: then what for they're made? that content im trying to put there is for a styling stuff